# How to unckeck checkboxes in another div when checkbox in one div is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've 3 div elements  namely part1 and part2 and part3

There are multiple checkboxes in each div

If checkboxes in part1 and part2 are checked then part3 should be unchecked. (Not working)

If checkbox in part3 is checked then the other should be unchecked (This is working)

The checkbox in part3 is uncheckable.

> HTML

```
<form>
<div class="chceckboxt">
<span class="popup"><b>Part 1</b><br></span><br>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="chceckboxt">
<span class="popup"><b>Part 2</b><br></span><br>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
<span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> <br></span>
</div>

<br><br>
<span class="popup"><b>Part 3</b><br></span><br>
<div class="noneabove">
<span class="popup">
  <span class="popup"><span class="popup"> <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" <br></span>
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

> JS :

```
$('.noneabove input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
    if(this.checked) {
    $('.chceckboxt input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});


$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
    $('.noneabove input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsorhp8b/19/)

Comment: Here'e the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qsorhp8b/19/

Comment: Do u want to use "and" or "or"?

Comment: (Part 1 and part2 ) or (part3)

Comment: If checkbox is uncheckable, meaning can not be checked, then how do you expect it to uncheck? Do you mean to make it a button?

Comment: That is my requirement. 1) To make it part3 checkable and 2) when any checkbox in either part 1 or part 2 is checked then uncheck part3.

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
    $('.noneabove input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    }
}); ` If I remove this part, One half is working fine.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the additional information in the comments. Code in comments is not as easy to read as formatted code in the question.

Comment: When asking a question, please include a minimal, reproducible example _in the question_. We don't need to see all your code--just enough to understand what you've tried (and are trying to do) so we can help you.

Comment: Added link to fiddle from comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the class name in your handler.
Also... you cannot have mutiple elements with same IDs, in this case checkboxes.
Change your JavaScript like this:

```
$('.noneabove input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
    if(this.checked) {
    $('.chceckboxt input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});


$('.chceckboxt input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
    $('.noneabove input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fp9Lcugz/)

Comment: My bad, Thank you so much.